# topological KC - space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space X is KC – space if every compact subsets are closed.

question:

Does a KC - space contains a minimal KC topology?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137660/katetov-kc-and-sequental-spaces.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is *no*; Bill Fleissner constructed a counterexample in ‘A $T_B$ space which is not Katetov $T_B$’, which is freely available [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250128845). (He uses the term $T_B$ *space* for your KC-space.)