# Min and max elements in lattices of KC ($= T_B$) topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

a space $(X,\tau )$  is said to
be minimal KC  if $(X,\tau )$ is KC and  no topology
on X which is strictly smaller  than $\tau$  is KC.

A space $(X,\tau)$  is  **minimal KC**   iff it is **KC and compact**.

A space $(X,\tau)$  is  **minimal KC**   iff it is **maxima compact**

Let $X $ and $Y$ be topological space.
$ f : X ‎\longrightarrow ‎Y‎ $ is called **closed**  , if for every closed subset $ F \subseteq X$, emage $ f( F) $ will be closed in $Y$.

**question:**
Is it right? Why?

> **(1):Let ‎$ f : X ‎\longrightarrow ‎Y‎ $ be a continuous   map from a maximal compact space $X$ to topological space $Y$.  then $Y$ is maximal compact  iff $f$ is closed.**
>
> (2): Does f need to be **surjective**? why?

Comment: "...is called..." What is it called?! And what is "maximal compact space" ? Maximal *where* ?

Comment: Of possible relevance: [topological KC - space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453595/topological-kc-space) (StackExchange) and [Katetov - KC and sequental spaces](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137660/katetov-kc-and-sequental-spaces) (MathOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is not closed; then there is a closed $F\subseteq X$ such that $f[F]$ is not closed in $Y$. $F$ is compact, so $f[F]$ is compact, and it follows that $Y$ is not $KC$. Since $Y$ is not $KC$, it cannot be minimal $KC$ and therefore cannot be maximal compact.

Now suppose that $Y$ is not maximal compact; then $Y$ is compact but not minimal $KC$, so $Y$ is not $KC$. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $Y$ that isn’t closed; $f^{-1}[K]$ is a closed subset of $X$, and $X$ is compact, so $f^{-1}[K]$ is compact. Moreover, $X$ is $KC$, so $f^{-1}[K]$ is closed. Finally, $f$ is surjective, so $K=f[f^{-1}[K]]$, and $K$ is therefore the non-closed image of the closed set $f^{-1}[K]$; this shows that $f$ is not closed. Surjectivity is needed to ensure that $K=f[f^{-1}[K]]$: if $f$ were not surjective, we might have $K\supsetneqq f[f^{-1}[K]]$.