# Sufficient condition for a Topological space to be Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I know that every Hausdorff space $X$ has the following property:

***$A\subset X$ is compact $\Rightarrow A$ is closed***

In other words, that is necessary for $X$ to be Hausdorff. But is it sufficient? If not, what information can get from this property?

Comment: [It isn't](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453595/topological-kc-space)

Comment: A standard example of a $KC$-space (compact sets are closed) that is not Hausdorff is $\Bbb Q^*$, the one-point compactification of the rationals.

Comment: I wonder what can we conclude from this $KC$-property. If it doesn't imply $X$ is $T_2$, does it imply $T_0$ or $T_1$? Or what additional property(ies) would guarantee $X$ is Hausdorff (or $T_0, T_1$ etc)?